# OVPN AS - Server can't reach client with local IP

Tags: openvpn

I have a OpenVPN Access Server running on a Ubuntu machine and a OpenVPN client also running on a Ubuntu. The client itself has a LTE interface which is used for the internet connection, so there is no router or so involved on the client site.
The VPN connection is configured in a way that the client can access only the server (X.X.X.X/32) and the remaining internet traffic is not routed through the tunnel. The server has full access to the client network (X.X.Y.0/24). When the connection is established the client can communicate with all server by using its fixed local IP addresses. Vice versa it doesn't work with the local client IP, but with the VPN IP address. So it seems that the client doesn't know what to do or how to handle the request from the VPN IP address area for local IPs.
Any help would be great.

PS: I don't know if other devices in the client network can be access by their local IP, because it's at the moment on my desk and not in the productive environment.

Comment: Can you please post your server and client configs?  Typically, to expose client CIDR blocks, you would use the `iroute` directive to expose client cidr ranges to the server.  You can read more about this [here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/expanding-the-scope-of-the-vpn-to-include-additional-machines-on-either-the-client-or-server-subnet/)

Comment: openVPN access server doesn't use the usual openvpn configuration files on the server site. The configuration stored in SQLite database files. The server is configured via a WebUI and the client configurations can be downloaded also from a WebUI.